# Validate Form Fields to send to Database

Tags: php

im currently sumitting info the database via a form i have created:

```
<form method="post" action="send.php">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="yourinfo" ><br/>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="Last Name" onFocus=this.value='' class="yourinfo"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Email Address" onFocus=this.value='' class="yourinfo"><br/>
    <input type="text" name ="date" id="datepicker" value="Enter Your Prediction" onFocus=this.value='' class="yourinfo"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" >
    </form>
```

i then have my php which is submitting it to the database:

```
<?php


$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$datepicker = $_POST['date'];

//get the correct format
$new_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date']));

mysql_connect ("localhost", "user", "pass") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("database");

$query="INSERT INTO table (id, firstname, lastname, email, date) 
VALUES ('NULL', '".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."',   '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_date)."')";


mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());  


header('Location: table.php');
?>
```

ive been told that i MUST validate the form before submittin anything to the database but im not entirely sure on how to do this, i know it something to do with **mysql_real_escape_string()** but im a little unsure of what to do

hope you can help

Here are the errors:

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'gezzamon'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/gezzamon/public_html/allymccoist/send.php on line 4

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/gezzamon/public_html/allymccoist/send.php on line 4

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'gezzamon'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/gezzamon/public_html/allymccoist/send.php on line 5

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/gezzamon/public_html/allymccoist/send.php on line 5

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'gezzamon'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/gezzamon/public_html/allymccoist/send.php on line 6

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/gezzamon/public_html/allymccoist/send.php on line 6

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'gezzamon'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/gezzamon/public_html/allymccoist/send.php on line 7

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/gezzamon/public_html/allymccoist/send.php on line 7

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/gezzamon/public_html/allymccoist/send.php:4) in /home/gezzamon/public_html/allymccoist/send.php on line 23
```

Comment: Told by me :) and you even kept my uppercase 'MUST' for emphasis!

Comment: Are you using mysql_real_escape_string before the connecting line? You should move every mysql_real_escape_string lines ($firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);...etc.) after the line that connects to the DB. It needs to be connected to the DB to be certain on what characters to escape.

Comment: ahhh.... this seems to have fixed it.  Sorry to sound stupid here but does doing this protect me from people being able to hack into the database from the form??

Answer (score 0):

You can at least check if they are empty or not, and use a regular expression to validate the email.
Also use PDO for your database, it will protect you from all forms of SQL Injection.

There are plenty of tutorials about PDO on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on all the variables to be used in your SQL statement.

```
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$datepicker = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
```

Ironically here, the one thing you don't need to escape is `$new_date` because you can already be certain it is in the valid and safe form `Y-m-d` (or it is `FALSE` if the date was bad). Doesn't hurt though.

```
$query="INSERT INTO table (id, firstname, lastname, email, date) 
  VALUES (NULL, '".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."',   '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_date)."')";
```

This is a little messy with all the quoting and concatenation.  In PHP you can use string interpolation like this:

```
$query="INSERT INTO table (id, firstname, lastname, email, date) 
  VALUES (NULL, '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '".mysql_real_escape_string($new_date)."')";
```

Comment: using this just returned a pile of errors when u submitted the form

Comment: @Gezzamondo and what were the errors? We can fix them if we know what they were.   Also, take the quotes off of `'NULL'`.

Comment: i dont have enough characters in here to post the errors, what your email address and ill email you

Comment: @Gezzamondo no, no don't post them in the comments or email. Post them as an edit to the original question above.